# Finding the flux through $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ when $z \ge 0$?

Tags: definite-integrals, divergence-operator

It's a sphere with radius a. I need to calculate the flux through $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ when $z \ge 0$. Using Gauss Law:

$$\iint \vec fd\vec S=\int(\nabla f)d^3r$$

I've calculated that the divergence is $\nabla f=4z$.

Solving using spherical coordinates I get:

$$\iint \vec fd\vec S=\pi a^4$$

This doesn't seem to be correct solution, since I seem to be missing a step.  Apparently I need to integrate another section, and subtract it from $\pi a^4$ but I'm not sure which. I'd appreciate an explanation

Comment: $f$ is unknown?

Comment: Yes, you need to subtract the flux through the bottom where $z=0, x^2+y^2=a^2$, pointing downward. This is because when you use Gauss Law, you are assuming the flux is through an enclosed region. So you automatically included the extra bottom boundary.

Comment: @KittyL So originally the left integral gives me the flux through the top and of the shape and the bottom. How do we know that we just want the flux through the top of the sphere?

Comment: It asks you to find the flux through the sphere when $z\geq 0$. The sphere only contains the top part. The bottom part is a plane. It is not included in the sphere.

Comment: @KittyL Is there a good reference in this context?

Comment: @KittyL ohh that makes sense. Here I thought the $z\ge 0$ was just for setting the limit of integration. That makes much more sense, thank you!

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: I think any calculus book should contain this material. There are online notes too. For example, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same result for the volume integral over the divergence:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{V} 4z \, dV 
&= \int\limits_0^a \pi \rho(z)^2 \, 4z \, dz \\
&= \int\limits_0^a \pi (a^2 - z^2) \, 4z \, dz \\
&= 4 \pi \int\limits_0^a (a^2 z - z^3) \, dz \\
&= 4 \pi \left[\frac{a^2}{2}z^2 - \frac{1}{4} z^4 \right]_{z=0}^{z=a} \\
&= 4 \pi \left( \frac{a^4}{2} - \frac{a^4}{4} \right) \\
&= \pi a^4
\end{align}
This corresponds to the flux through $\partial V$, which is the top half sphere ($x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2, z \ge 0$) and the disk of radius $a$ in the $x$-$y$-plane at $z=0$.

So you have to subtract the flow through the disk, for which one needs to know your $f$, or $f \cdot e_z$.